# CSS positioning problems (basic)

Tags: html, css, web, positioning

I'm designing a website and I need it to look something like this http://www.spookycraft.net/

excluding the slide show and javascript and such, I just need 4 separate clickable blocks in the middle of a webpage, I've tried to use `margin:auto` and then re-position it using `margin-left` and `margin-bottom` ect but when I use `margin-bottom` It just splits apart more and acts rather interestingly here's my current code keep in mind I also need it to look the same on a higher resolution screen which is why I was attempting to use `margin:auto;`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<table border="10px"; class="head">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/partners/hp/data-center-network-connect/images/Alliance_DCNC_700x200.jpg" > </>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    .tone{
        margin:auto;
    }
    .ttwo{
        margin:auto;
    }
    .tthree{
        margin:auto;
    }

    .tfour{
        margin:auto;
    }
    .head{
        margin:auto;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="5px"; class="tone"> 
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    <table border="5px"; class="ttwo">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    <table border="5px" class="tthree">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="5px" class="tfour">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'll be working to find a answer to my problem, and when I do I'll update this thread.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but the first two I see below give you what you need to hear. Don't use tables. The reason why your example doesn't work, though, is because you have each box in a separate `<tr>`. If you remove all the code between the first and second `td`s,  and between the third and fourth, it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use tables, they are a no-no in my books. Tables should not be used for structure in a HTML page these days, they should only be used for presenting data in a tabular format. Just use `<div>`s with a master wrapper `<div>` around them. Something like this is perfect:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing"><a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"></a></div>
    <div class="box spacing"><a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"></a></div>

    <div class="box spacing"><a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"></a></div>
    <div class="box spacing"><a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif" width="100%"></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  body{

        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .container{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:450px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
    .box{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#ccc;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    .spacing{
        margin-right:20px;
    }
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aRSNh/172/

Comment: Thank you very much, I won't be using tables like this for stuff like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with table design, but if you want to build it with `div` I have my code here

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"></div>
</div>
```

with this css

```
.container {
    width: 680px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice library for fast CSS development is Twitter bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

Here is a quick example using bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Layout Demo</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-   combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 100px 0px; 0px; 0px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset6 span3"> <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a> </div>
    <div class="span3"> <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a> </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset6 span3"> <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a> </div>
    <div class="span3"> <a href="www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.wilsoninfo.com/300x300.gif"> </> </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/iKgsmZ/preview